# forming successive list of numbers in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list like this `[11,12,7,8,9,10,4,1]` and need output like `[[11,12], [7,10], 4, 1]]`. If the count of successive number is more than 2 then need only first and last number of that sequence.

What I tried is -

```
list([A, B|C], [A], [B|C]) :-
    A + 1 =\= B.
list([A, B|C], [A|T], Back) :-
    A + 1 =:= B,
    list([B|C], T, Back).

break([], []).
break(L, [H | T]) :-
    list(L, H, Back),
    break(Back, T).
```

What I am getting by this is `[[11,12], [7,8,9,10], [4], [1]]` instead.

Comment: Why not `[[11,12], [7,10], [4], [1]]` instead?

Comment: Same homework assignment as presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428666/prolog-remove-the-elements-between-the-first-and-the-last-elements-in-a-list) perhaps...

Comment: Even `break([1], Ys).` fails in your program.